# Convert utc time into local time of specifc format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a date string of format `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss` but its UTC which I want to convert to local. How can I do it using moment library?

```
const dateStr = '20.09.2018 16:12:37';
const format = 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss';

// for local time of UTC +3.00 new date Str will be 20.09.2018 19:12:37
```

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/

Comment: Its not clear from the docs, thats why its asked here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`moment.utc(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) to parse your string using UTC mode

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.
>
> If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use `moment.utc()` instead of `moment()`

Then you can use [`local()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/) to convert  it to local time:

> Sets a flag on the original moment to use local time to display a moment instead of the original moment's time.

Please note that since you input `dateStr` is not in ISO 8601/RCF 2822 recognized format you have to [specify format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) when parsing it. Morover moment tokens are case sensitive so you have to use uppercase `YYYY` instead of `yyyy` to parse years and uppercase `DD` to parse day of the month since lowercase `dd` stands for day of the week (Mon, Tue, etc).

Here a live sample:

```js
const dateStr = '20.09.2018 16:12:37';
const format = 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss';

console.log(moment.utc(dateStr, format).local().format(format));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Have a look at [Local vs UTC vs Offset](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/) guide to better understand how UTC and locale mode work in momentjs.

Answer (score 0):

To convert from UTC to Local you need to use **moment.local()** method

```
const dateStr = '20.09.2018 16:12:37';
const format = 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss';

var newDate = moment.utc().format(format);
var temp= moment.utc(newDate, format);
var local = moment(temp).local().format(format);
```

[More info on the official Documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/)

Comment: I apologize for that, I was typing in a hurry, just fixed it now